# JSHint unused variable

Tags: javascript, jshint

In JSHint I would like to use the [undef option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#undef). The issue I'm having is I have a variable that is declared in one file but is actually used in another piece. The variable holds an object of analytic tracking elements that I pass as a parameter to my code that initalizes the tracking code. The tracking code is a library that I would like to keep separate. The idea is just include this tracking code library. You then setup your element tracking object in your main js file and pass it as a parameter to the initlize method. JSHint flags this this tracking object as a defined but not used. How can I tell JSHint that the tracking object is actually used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the exported directive

```
/*exported variableName */
```

Comment: OP is doing the opposite. Defining a var in File A, File B uses it. OP is getting an error in File A because a var is defined but not used.

Comment: @JustinWood Whoops, should not answer while eating. Fixed it with the right answer.